# What is the max. capacity of RAM in 32-bit machine? Why it is not 16GB?

Tags: 32-bit, ramdisk

This question is inspired from a question in stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6895412/32-bit-64-bit-os/6895452#6895452)

To what I know,

for 32bit machines, we can have 2^32 combination set of instructions.

so for a max capacity of a RAM in 32-bit machine, it should be able to accommodate 2^32 instructions set, which is

2^32 = 4294967296 instructions set

so as 32 bits = 4 bytes, the RAM capacity should be 4294967296 * 4 bytes = 17179869186 bytes

which is same as -->

**17179869186/1024 = 16777216 kB**

**16777216/1024 = 16384 MB**

**16384/1024 = 16GB**

so I guess the max capacity of RAM that a 32-bit machine can hold is 16GB.

But sounds like 4GB is the correct answer. What's wrong with me???

Comment: You're confusing "instruction sets" with "memory addressing" to say the least. :)

Comment: appreciate if you can help correct me

Comment: @Kit, you basic confusion is that the size of a *pointer* is not the same as the size of the thing *pointed to*. A pointer on a 32-bit machine is 4 bytes wide, but a single memory address (the thing that the pointer points to) is only one byte wide.

Comment: The confusion here is between the size of the processor word (32 bits in this case) and the size of the addressable memory unit (in the case of current general purpose machines that is 1 byte = 8 bits). So yes, the processor can load four addressable memory units at a time.

Comment: @dmckee - Thanks for clearing that up, now I understand OP's confusion.  I didn't even think of the word size, and was wondering where on earth the factor of four was coming from.

Comment: I also don't understand the close votes here - this seems like a real question to me (but then, that's why I answered it).

Comment: @Shinrai: I agree, how can I reopen  it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

RAM is addressed by the byte.  There are 2^32 addresses possible in this situation, so a maximum of 4294967296 bytes (2^32) can be addressed. That means the effective maximum on addressible memory is 4294967296 bytes, which is 4 gigabytes.

Comment: well, but one set of address should occupy 4 bytes (32bits), so why not 16GB?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but it's very straightforward.  A 32-bit processor can natively address 2^32 bytes. 2^32 bytes = 4GB.  That's all there is to it - I'm not sure where you're getting this "address=4 bytes" thing from.  I have edited my answer to perhaps be a bit more explicit.

Comment: @Kit each memory address *isn't* 4 bytes - each is ***1*** byte. A 4 byte long variable (for example) will cross over 4 memory locations. So your multiplication by 4 is irrelevant.

Comment: @DMA: Oh yes! I think I understand now. I mix up sth. I always regard that memory address is stored in 4bytes

Comment: Just to expand this explanation, there is no law of nature that says that the size of whatever an address points to has to be one byte (8 bits). If you have a memory architecture where each memory cell is 8 bytes (64 bits) instead, you could address 2^32*8 bytes with a 32 bit address. But normally you address memory as bytes, even to this day.

Comment: The reason for addressing bytes is that many data formats are sequences of bytes, most notably text.

Comment: Commenters are making good point, especially regarding the reasons the addressing is like this (and the fact that there's no reason it couldn't be otherwise, but then there's not really even a law of nature that says we have to use powers of two or 8-bit bytes or what have you)

Comment: As with a few other similar questions some of the issue here is simply terminology. It is at best misleading to say, for example, "each memory address is 1 byte". The _addresses_ are as large as the processor supports - 4 bytes on x86 (assuming no PAE, etc.). A better way to think of it is that each _addressable memory location_ **contains** one byte. (That's on today's common processors, but as noted by Shinrai, a lot of computing has been done with processors with different word sizes.)